# Trocar de username destrói os commits?

Tags: git

Troquei o meu username para um mais profissional. Antes de trocar vi que tinha uns avisos que poderia  acontecer erros ao fazer isso, mas não dei importância porque dizia que eram casos raros.

Acontece que hoje percebi que os meus commits de antes de eu trocar de username desapareceram. Dou `git log` e `git reflog` e não aparace eles. Como teste exclui um repositório localmente e clonei ele de novo, mas continuou na mesma.

Alguém sabe se há como eu recuperar esses commits?

Comment: Vou sugerir que entre em contato diretamente com o pessoal do GitHub. Além de informarem como proceder, pode ser que tenham poder de reverter.

Comment: @Rafael, o Git não exclui os commits feitos com o usuário antigo se você trocar de usuário. Você consegue reproduzir novamente o problema, detalhando como fez isto e que mensagens de aviso recebeu? Sem estas informações, fica difícil adivinhar a causa.

Comment: O que é "trocar de username"?